# Como fazer um conjunto de imagens passarem em js?

Tags: php, javascript

Bom a minha pergunta é a seguinte:

Eu tenho um formulário em PHP que ao clicar o PHP sorteia uma das seguintes cores: amarelo, laranja, vermelho, roxo ou verde.

Bom o que eu queria saber era se havia forma de o PHP passar essa cor sorteada para o javascript e em javascript o javascript fazer "rodar a roleta" de forma a que saísse a cor selecionada pelo PHP.

Abaixo mostra alguns exemplos da minha roleta, a roleta quando se passa o mouse, a cor fica mais forte.

Exemplo:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sua dúvida é em passar a informação do PHP pro javascript ou montar a roleta?

Comment: Exato, a minha duvida basicamente é a seguinte, o PHP diz ao JS que a cor que caiu é o Vermelho, entao quero q apareça as cores por ordem até chegar ao vermelho de modo a "simular" que caiu o vermelho.

Comment: O que você fez até agora?